# Merge two data frames with different left_on and right_on length lists

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the following problem. I have two data frames and would like to merge them based on two columns in the first data frame and on one column in the second data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

new1 = pd.DataFrame({0:['a','b','c'], 1:['q1','q2','q3'], 2:['t3','t2','t1']})
new2 = pd.DataFrame({0:['aq1','bq2','cq3'], 1:['la1','la2','la3']})
pd.merge(new1,new2, how='inner', left_on=[0,1], right_on=[0])
```

This code does not work since

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

Does pandas have some standard methods for this case? Or the only way to solve the problem is to create addition column in new1 data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

new1 = pd.DataFrame({0:['a','b','c'], 1:['q1','q2','q3'], 2:['t3','t2','t1']})
new1[3] = new1[0] + new1[1]
new2 = pd.DataFrame({0:['aq1','bq2','cq3'], 1:['la1','la2','la3']})
print(pd.merge(new1,new2, how='inner', left_on=[3], right_on=[0]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the sum in the merge instead of creating a new column.

```
pd.merge(new1,new2, how='inner', left_on=[new1[0]+new1[1]], right_on=[0])
```

You get

```
    0_x 1_x 2   0_y 1_y
0   a   q1  t3  aq1 la1
1   b   q2  t2  bq2 la2
2   c   q3  t1  cq3 la3
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you!